# How can you use the langchain planner.create_openapi_agent with dynamic endpoints with variables?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I am using the planner functionality in langchain.agents.agent_toolkits.openapi to interact with an API using natural language queries. I am using the following code:

`llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)`

`agent = planner.create_openapi_agent(api_spec, requests_wrapper, llm, verbose=True)`

`query = "Which users are enrolled on the course that has the course id ABC1002."`

`agent.run(query)`

When I run the agent, the chain runs successfully to start with and recognises the correct endpoint to call:

GET /learn/api/public/v1/courses/{courseId}/users

this requires substituting the {courseId} part of that endpoint with an id from the query (in this case the id ABC1002), resulting in a get request as follows:

GET /learn/api/public/v1/courses/ABC1002/users

The agent correctly substitutes the courseId variable producing the correct endpoint format that should successfully retrieve the correct data from the endpoint, however the error that I receive from the agent is that the endpoint does not exist. Looking at the error message detail, it seems that because the endpoint has been changed from the original endpoint (/learn/api/public/v1/courses/{courseId}/users) in the yaml file by injecting the courseId into it, it is being rejected by the agent. I have copied the full chain output and error message below.

I want to know if it is possible to let the agent accept the endpoint with a variable inserted into it, so it is not rejected when the chain runs

`Entering new  chain...

Action: api_planner

Action Input: I need to find the right API calls to get the users enrolled in the course with id ABC1002

Observation: 1. GET /learn/api/public/v1/courses/{courseId}/users - This API call will return a list of user memberships for the specified course.
Replace {courseId} with ABC1002 to get the users enrolled in that course.

Thought:I'm ready to execute the API calls.

Action: api_controller

Action Input: GET /learn/api/public/v1/courses/ABC1002/users - This API call will return a list of user memberships for the specified course.

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 bb_agent.run(user_query)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/agents/agent_toolkits/openapi/planner.py in _create_and_run_api_controller_agent(plan_str)
243             docs = endpoint_docs_by_name.get(endpoint_name)
244             if not docs:
--> 245                 raise ValueError(f"{endpoint_name} endpoint does not exist.")
246             docs_str += f"== Docs for {endpoint_name} == \n{yaml.dump(docs)}\n"
247

ValueError: GET /learn/api/public/v1/courses/ABC1002/users endpoint does not exist.`